# Showing two functions have equal Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.  If $(x_n)$ is a sequence converging to $x$ with $(x_n) \subseteq [a,b]$ and $f(w)=g(w)$ except when $w=x_i$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$, how can I show $\int_{a}^{b} f = \int_{a}^{b} g$?

I'm only sure about how to work from the definition of Riemann integrable functions. Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Since $f,g \in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ there is a $\delta > 0$ so that if $\dot{P}$ is a tagged partition of $[a,b]$ satisfying $||\dot{P}|| < \delta$ then we have $$\left | S(f,\dot{P}) - \int_{a}^{b} f \right | < \epsilon$$ and $$\left | S(g,\dot{P}) - \int_{a}^{b} g \right | < \epsilon$$
I think to work from here I need to be able to say something about $$\left | S(f,\dot{P}) - S(g,\dot{P}) \right |$$
I know that $$\left | S(f,\dot{P}) - S(g,\dot{P}) \right | =\left | \sum_{i=1}^{n}(f(t_i)-g(t_i))(x_i-x_{i-1})\right |$$
Now I think $f(t_i)-g(t_i)=0$ except it $t_i \in (x_n)$ so I only need to worry about the times that the $t_i \in (x_n)$.  Since $f,g$ are bounded, the worst value this difference can have is the case when $f(x_i)$ is at its maximum value and $g(x_i)$ is at its minimum value.  Also we have $(x_i-x_{i-1})< \delta $.  Assuming the preceding is correct, my confusion is about how many times $f(t_i)-g(t_i)$ can take its maximum value.  Is there a way to count these?  Do I even need to be able to count them? I think if I knew a maximum number of times this could happen, I could define a new $\delta$ allowing result to hold.

Comment: Do you know that the statement is true if there are only finitely many $x_n$?

Comment: Yes, my problem here is showing that I only need to worry about a finite number of terms.

Comment: Do you know that if $f , g$ differs only at **finitely** many points, then $\int_a^b f  = \int_a^b g$? (This is not exactly your question, but easier)

Comment: I think I have proven that; the proof is similar to the one I attempted above but since it is given that there are a finite number of points, the set of such points has a finite order which can be used to define $\delta$ such that the result follows.  Can something similar be done here?  In particular, how do i know $f,g$ only differ at finitely many points?

Comment: Given a partition $P$ where the Riemann sums $S(f,P)$ and $S(g,P)$ land within $\epsilon$ of $\int f$ and $\int g$ (for the respective functions), you can refine it so that $x_i$ lies in the interval $(a_i,b_i) \subset (x_i - \delta 2^{-i}, x_i + \delta 2^{-i})$.  This way, even if some $t_k$ coincide with points of $(x_n)$, the contribution to the sum is at most $\delta (\|f\|_{\infty} + \|g\|_{\infty})$.  Take $\delta \to 0$ to show that the discrepancy is negligible.

Comment: The sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ so if $P$ is a tagged partition  $(a=a_0<a_1<...<a_n=b)$  with $||P||<d$ there are at most  two $j$ such that $\{n : x_n \in [a_j,a_{j+1}]\}$ is infinite, With a total length of less than $2 d$ ...... BTW counting occurrences of maximal  values won't do anything on this Q. There exists a continuous $h : [0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that  for each $x \in [0,1]$ and  $0\le x-e<x+e\le 1$, the set $ \{y\in (x-e,x+e) :h(y)=h(x)\}$ has the cardinal of the Reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer we want to use the fact that if two functions differ only at **finitely** many points, then the Riemann integral are the same. Using this we can more or less get rid of all the analysis to deal with partial sums.

Also you have to use the essentially fact that $x_n \to x$. First of all, for all $\epsilon >0$, we have

$$\int_a^b f = \int_a ^{x-\epsilon} f + \int_{x-\epsilon}^{x + \epsilon} f + \int_{x+\epsilon} ^b f$$

and similar for $g$ (we assume $a <x-\epsilon < x+\epsilon <b$). Now as $x_n \to x$, there is $N_\epsilon \in \mathbb N$ so that $|x- x_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N_\epsilon$. Thus away from $[x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon]$, $f$ and $g$ differs only at finitely many points. In particular,

$$\int_a ^{x-\epsilon} f = \int_a ^{x-\epsilon} g,\ \ \ \int_{x+\epsilon} ^b f = \int_{x+\epsilon} ^b g. $$

This implies

$$\left| \int_a^b f - \int_a^b g \right| \le \left|\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+ \epsilon} (f-g)\right| \le 4M \epsilon,$$

where $M$ is the upper bound of $f$, $g$. As $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, take $\epsilon \to 0$ to get

$$\int_a ^b f = \int_a^b g.$$

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: Where does the 4 come from?

Comment: $f-g \le M +M = 2M$ @user275778

Answer (score 0):

It seems like if you prove that $|S(g, P) - S(f, P)| < \varepsilon$, then it means that $\int_a^b g(x) dx = S(g, P)$. Also, $|S(f, P) - S(f, P)| = 0 < \varepsilon$, so $\int_a^b f(x) dx = S(g, P)$. Hence $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b g(x) dx$.